# Adding IDs to urls to open up namespace - SEO considerations?

Tags: seo, url, url-rewriting

I'm working with a site that has millions of pages along the lines of:

```
domain.com/entity/John_Smith
domain.com/entity/Google
domain.com/entity/HTML
```

One of the problems is that particularly for people names, there are lots of duplicates, so we end up with

```
domain.com/entity/John_Smith
domain.com/entity/John_Smith_(explorer)
domain.com/entity/John_Smith_(politician)
```

We instead want to move to a url scheme (much like StackExchange) like:

`domain.com/entity/1234/John_Smith` (where 1234 is a unique ID).

I assume that if we:

- put in 301 redirects from every old page to new page
- updated our sitemap with the new urls

then we'll be pretty much covered. But could there be any short-term SEO implications that we should expect?  (Dips in traffic, etc.?)  Are there any pieces of this puzzle that we're missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a risk with URL changes of SEO problems, ranking loss, and traffic declines.   When correctly implemented with 301 redirects, it can go perfectly fine, but it doesn't always do so.

I recommend changing URLs only when there is an overwhelming need.  If you do want to change URLs you should consider gentler changes as well:

- Chang the URL structure only for new URLs.  Leave the old URLs grandfathered at their old locations.
- Or change the URLs slowly over time in batches.

Answer (score 4):

If you correctly put in 301 redirects and update your sitemap, the site will be fine. However...

What are you trying to gain from this change?

The Stack Exchange-style hierarchy doesn't make sense for what it seems you're trying to accomplish (a Wikipedia-style website?). What you currently have makes more sense in terms of organizing the information:

```
domain.com/entity/John_Smith
domain.com/entity/John_Smith_(explorer)
domain.com/entity/John_Smith_(politician)
```

That's a fair amount of work for no apparent benefit.

Comment: The immediate case is that we have some data sources where we know someone's name, but we don't necessarily have enough information to append something like (explorer) or (politician) without a ton of work. Right now we'd have to do something like John_Smith_(1) or John_Smith_(2) until we figured it out, which is a pretty bad user experience on our site.

Comment: I would actually pay more attention to the titles then to URLs. When you think about it, there's a bunch of commerce website dealing with similar issues all the time with IDs, and it's working perfectly fine.

Comment: @JedChristiansen What makes `/John_Smith_1` or `/John_Smith_2` any worse than `/72543425/John_Smith` or `/25357443/John_Smith` in terms of user experience? If the latter makes development easier, then I'd understand the case. I can't make any strong recommendation in good faith without understanding the purpose of the site.

Comment: My feeling is that most users don't look at URLs, and search engines wouldn't care either way. I'd worry that you're spending time on a non-issue, and adding complexity (URL changes, redirects) that can break.

Comment: @JohnMueller Agreed. P.S. I know it's more Gary's thing, but if you're ever at Google Japan, I'd like to buy you dinner for all the help you've provided me and the community ;)